# What's this equation called (one more each iteration, find total for given iteration)?

Tags: terminology

Say you have +1 on first iteration, +2 on second, and so on until N, and you want to know the total.  That's easily calculate using (N * (N + 1) ) / 2.  What's that equation or technique called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which technique you are talking about, [one technique](http://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar) was discovered by Gauss when he was about 8 years old.

His teacher supposedly posed the question of finding the sum of the first $100$ positive integers to keep the class busy during the long periods, and it turns out Gauss found a way to do it quickly. You could call the technique Gauss' Trick, Gauss' Method, Gaussian method.

The numbers are called [Triangular Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The $N$th triangular number, which corresponds to the sum of the first $N$ positive integers, is given by

$$T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

The "technique", so to speak, is called summation, usually denoted with a $\Sigma$, like so (I should note that the formula you've listed is incorrect): $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: fixed it thanks